# Pythonic way to extract region name from zone (AWS/GCloud)

Tags: python, list, extract

I'm new to Python and I was wondering, what is the best way to extract the region's name from a zone name.

For example:

```
GCP:

 - us-east1-c
 - europe-west2-b

AWS:

 - eu-west-2
 - ap-northeast-1
```

In bash, I would use:

```
echo "zone"|rev|cut -f2- -d-|rev"
```

In Python, I used:

```
'-'.join(zone.split('-')[:-1]),
```

I know it doesn't really matter, but I would like to do it in the pythonic way.

Thanks in advance!

Oh, expected output is if zone is us-east1-b

us-east1

Comment: so you want to remove last 2 characters? i.e. you want `us-east1` instead of `us-east1-b`

Comment: based on what I've seen in region names, all of them are X-Y-Z. Where X is the "region/continent" like us, eu, ap. Y is the location north/east/south/west, and Z is the DC id. So, based on this, I just want to remove the DC id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is enough using `rsplit`:

```
zone = 'us-east1-b'
print(zone.rsplit('-', 1)[0])
# us-east1
```

Or simply `split` will do:

```
zone = 'us-east1-b'
lst = zone.split('-')
print("{}-{}".format(lst[0], lst[1]))
# us-east1
```

Answer (score 0):

ok based on your comments I see `String slicing` will do the work for you.
Read more about it [here](https://docs.python.org/2.3/whatsnew/section-slices.html)

Try this - `print "us-east1-b"[:-2]`

Comment: thanks, but I don't know for sure, that the dc id will be always 1 char long. if for example a zone is us-east-12 then the result will be us-east-

Comment: got it, my answer won't handle such case. Need to update it. Thanks.